# Rename files within a folder - Python

Tags: python, file, directory

How can I rename files inside a folder without knowing their original name? For example I have a file.jpg and without knowing what it's called I want to call it test.jpg, this with all the files inside a folder.

Comment: Use os.listdir(src_dir) to get the list of all files and then rename using os.rename()

Comment: You cannot rename all the files to the same name. Please rephrase your question because it doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import glob
# Getting all files in a folder (including hidden files)
files = os.listdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads"))

# Getting all .jpg files in a directory
jpeg_files = glob.glob(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/*.jpeg"))

print(jpeg_files)
os.rename(jpeg_files[0], os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/test.jpeg"))
```

If you want to rename all of the `.jpeg` files, then replace the last line with:

```
for file in jpeg_files:
    os.rename(file, os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/test.jpeg"))
```

Right now I'm using `os.expanduser()` just so that it's easier for people to test